# Informatica: Write data into multiple files based on State name

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have table with a column called State. My requirement is to read data from the table and write it into multiple files based on State name. I'm using Informatica PowerCenter as ETL tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mapping as below:

```
Source --> SQ (sort data state name)--> Expression --> Transaction Control --> Target
```

Expression: Create a variable port to store previous value of state and a output port flag.

```
flag = IIF(state = var_state,0,1)
var_state = state
```

In Transaction Control Transformation, use TC_COMMIT_BEFORE when Flag = 1

Add Filename port to Target and map state name as filename.

Comment: I have tried the same and it is working perfectly. However, when I added timestamp to filename (ie filename = statename||'_'||SYSDATE) , I'm getting multiple files for some states. The table is having more than a few million records, is there any size limit for the target file?

Comment: That's probably because you're using SYSDATE. It will give the exact time at the record processing, so the file name could change. Please use SESSSTARTTIME and time. All records should have same time stamp if you use SESSSTARTTIME

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using post shell command:

```
Output file --> Name of output file of Informatica.
$2 --> assume 2nd field is the statement. Replace it as per your file

    awk -F\| '{print>$2}' outputfile
```