# To print TIMESTAMP into Target table in Informatica

Tags: informatica

I want to print same TIMESTAMP(session start time) for all the records in Target table using mapping parameter and variable option.

Can you please help me to solve this?

Comment: A similar issue has been mentioned in correct answer's comment :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087907/informatica-write-data-into-multiple-files-based-on-state-name

Answer (score 1):

You can use SESSIONSTARTTIME build-in variable for that purpose.